# Propagate error back to user in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to propagate an error back to the user if their input is wrong.

Here's the code that should throw the error:

```
var sql2 = "select COD_id from COD_Codes where COD_name = @Value and COD_COT_id = @codeId";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
            cmd2.CommandText = sql2;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", value);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeId", result);
            cmd2.Connection = connection;
            cmd2.Transaction = transaction;
            var code = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
            if (code == 0)
            {
                throw new  ApplicationException(string.Format(@"({0}) is not a valid data for this credit report. Please check with your sys admin if this is a new data value", code));
            }
            return code;
```

This code is a few levels below my controller which looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage SaveCreditReport(GrowData growData)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = CreateSqlConnection())
            {
                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var service = CreateCreditService(connection, transaction);

                        var user = GetUser(service);

                        if (log.IsInfoEnabled)
                            log.InfoFormat("Save credit report called by user '{0}' ",
                                user.UserName);

                        var growValues = growData.GrowRows.Select(growRow => new GrowValue() { Mnemonic = growRow.Mnemonic, Time = growRow.Time, Value = growRow.Value }).ToList();

                        var growCompValues = growData.GrowCompRows.Select(compRow => new GrowCompRowValue() { Mnemonic = compRow.Mnemonic, Value = compRow.Value }).ToList();

                        var reportId = service.SaveGrowCreditData(user.Id, growData.CompanyId, growValues, growCompValues, growData.Publish);

                        var message = this.Request.CreateResponse<int?>(HttpStatusCode.OK, reportId);

                        transaction.Commit();

                        return message;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure how and what kind of exception I need to throw to propagate the error back to user level. I don't want the standard "500 internal server error" message but instead the one that I've formatted in the code.

Can I just throw a new httpresponseexception instead of ApplicationException directly from the code? Will it then propagate back to controller level and unto the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your catch method use [CreateErrorResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127064(v=vs.118).aspx) to create a response with whatever HttpStatusCode is appropriate:

```
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
    return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, ex);
}
```

A caveat from the documentation:

> The request must be associated with an HttpConfiguration instance. An HttpResponseMessage whose content is a serialized representation of an HttpError instance [is returned]

Comment: Thank you. Its working great now.

Users will be so happy to know they did something wrong :)